# Is there a way to convert byte into IFormFile c# .net 4.5

Tags: c#, http-post, .net-4.5, iformfile

I have a project implemented in .NET 4.5, and for some reason, I cannot change it. I want to post a photo to a web API that is implemented with .NET Core. The API endpoint uses HTTP POST, and its input type is generic ICollection that its type is IFormFile. However, I am unable to send even one picture because I can only send byte types to the API. How can I solve this problem? Here is my code:

```
 using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(ServiceInfo.VIPCParams["DMSUri"].Value);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
               // client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", responseModelLogin.Token);

                // string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parameters);
              // HttpContent content = new ByteArrayContent(uploadRequest.File);

               HttpContent content = new ByteArrayContent(uploadRequest.File);

                //HttpContent content = new StreamContent(stream);

                //content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");



                //using (var stream = new MemoryStream(uploadRequest.File))
                //{
                //    await documentRepository.UploadFile(stream);
                //}


               // content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("multipart/form-data");
                var multipartContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
                multipartContent.Add(content);

               // multipartContent.Add(new StreamContent(content));

                HttpResponseMessage res = client.PostAsync(url, multipartContent).Result;
                string data = res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                mSUploadResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DMSUploadResponse>(data);
            }
```

Comment: Pleaee do not post images of code or data please only paste in as text

Comment: Looks like you just need to do multiple calls to `multipartContent.Add` with each inner content object. Also don't use `.Result` as you risk deadlocks, instead do `await`

Comment: Sorry, I edited my post and copied my code here.

Comment: I'm confused because I tried using multipartContent.Add to add a photo to my post request, but it didn't work. When I tried sending the request with a POST method, the server returned an error saying that there were no photos to upload

Comment: Since I can't see your API code, its hard to determine exactly what is going on. However, from my experience working with Multipart data in .NET APIs, I've learned that performing `ReadFormAsync()` on the `Request` object that is part of the API controller implementation works well. This yields an `IFormCollection` object, which contains within it an `IFormFileCollection` object that contains all the files found within the form data.

Comment: I believe this is a more proper way to receive/parse multipart data in .NET, though I guess it depends on your version. Mine uses .NET 6.0, so its possible this doesn't exist in .NET 4.5 and is entirely unhelpful. I'm just putting it out there either way.